# Why is the MVC RuleEditor is too slow loading data sources

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

We have implemented an instance of MVC RuleEditor  on the server side The MVC version is loading data is slower than ASP RuleEditor loading. Both controls utilize the same data sources and renders the same rules yet the MVC version calling the GetClientSettings() takes significantly longer causing the web app to time out.

I was wonder if anyone has any idea on how to improve the performance on the MVC control, specifically GetClientSettings()?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Code Effects rule editor does not do anything special on MVC. All processing is absolutely the same on all .NET web platforms, including the MVC platform.